# Regular expressions handling

Tags: c#, regex, expression

I want to write a regular expression that can match the following strings:

```
OFF
ON
String
Valve
```

I was thinking to write `^(?<arrivingString>[a-zA-Z]{?})$`.

Now I don't know what to write within the curly brackets, as the value of arriving string is different and random.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2270/Inside-C-Second-Edition-String-Handling-and-Regula

Comment: so you want to match strings that contain any of those words

Comment: If the value you are matching is varying, you do not need to specify a min and max (which is what you are doing with the curly braces). You can use one of the repetition operators (+*) to match the varying text.

Comment: Can you give an example of text that should be matched and an example of text that should not.

Comment: I am sending command and in the sending command I also have to specify what response i expect to receive. In the send I tell that my resonse should be: `^Response[:](?<arrivingString>[a-zA-Z]{?})$`. So my response is a string and one of the above mentioned word appear in the **arrivingString**. So how to take into account the varaible word lenght .

Comment: So later I can match using the **arrivingString** group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?<arrivingString>(OFF|ON|String|Valve)).*
```

This matches those 4 words only provided:

- Mutiline is enabled for the Regex
- The words are at the start of each line

This Regex will match every line in it's entirety provided it starts with any of those 4 strings. The captured group `arrivingString`will contain whichever of the four words was found.